# Working with quotes when using NPM package variables

Tags: node.js, npm, jestjs

I have a jest command that looks like this:

```
npx jest index.test --testMatch "**/test/*.cjs"
```

This looks in the `./test` directory for test files matching the extension `.cjs`.

The above command works as expected.

However, I'm having an issue when trying to alias this command via NPM using `package.json` variables.

Here's the file:

```
// package.json
...
"config": {
   "testmatch": "--testMatch \"**/test/*.cjs\""
},
"scripts": {
  "test1": "npx jest index.test $npm_package_config_testmatch",
  "test2": "npx jest index.test --testMatch \"**/test/*.cjs\""
}
...
```

For `npm run test1` I get the following result:

```
No tests found, exiting with code 1
...
```

For `npm run test2` I get the desired result, i.e. Jest runs all the tests and outputs the result.

The two are essentially the same commands, but `test1` doesn't work.

When I used the `--debug` flag for Jest (for both commands) I noticed that Jest appears to be receiving two different values for `testMatch`:

```
// npm run test1
...
"testMatch": [
  "\"**/test/*.cjs\""
],
...
```

```
// npm run test2
...
"testMatch": [
  "**/test/*.cjs"
],
...
```

This would explain why the `npm run test1` fails: the pattern is malformed.

Is there some way to deal with the quote character `"` when using them inside NPM package variables?

Comment: Did you try removing the quotes from `$.config.testmatch`? Also note you may want `test/**/*.cjs`, based on your description.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for the edit. Yes I did. It does work without the quotes; I forgot to mention that. However, there are quite a few commands that require quotes so I'd like to know if there's a way to handle them in this specific scenario.